# Android Oreo Background Location Limit works occasionally

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using FusedLocationProvider for my app to collect location every few seconds. After I upgrade my Samsung S8 to Android 8.0 recently, I found my app cannot get new location after running at background for a while(10 mins-20 mins). This happens only a few times, probably less than 10% of the tests. Then I tested on Google Pixel phone which run Android 8.1. I put the app to background and did some test. I keep receiving new location every few seconds. However there was one time that I can get only one new location every 5 minutes. Anybody know how exactly this background location limit works.

1, In what situation this feature will be triggered(looks like put app to background won't always trigger this)?

2, How often can I expect a new location once this limit been triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got more detail after some testing.

1, If your app is using FusedLocationProvider, the location requested by other app may affect this location limitation. By force killing all other location related apps, this limitation will kick in once you put your app to background.

2, For Samsung S8, I got one new location around every 3 mins. For Google Pixel, I got one new location every 5 mins. During that 3-5 mins, the last location from the location manager keeps the same.